# DISTINCT column combination with permutations

Tags: postgresql, distinct

My postgresql column structure looks like this:

```
id  | from | to
---------------
1   |  A   |  B
2   |  A   |  B 
3   |  C   |  D
```

Now I want an result which looks like this:

```
 res 
-----
'A:B'
'B:A' 
'C:D'
'D:C'
```

where the first and the rows are permuted from A:B to B:A and 'C:D' to 'D:C' and the second column is omitted due to distinct operation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks more like a stack overflow question yet Union will give a distinct combination.

```
SELECT concat("from",':',"to") as res From Table
UNION
SELECT concat("to",':',"from") From Table
```

Comment: You could also use the string concatenation operator - double pipe (||), i.e. `SELECT depart || ':' || arrive FROM res UNION &c...` - **might** (test) on be more efficient with big tables? On the other hand, `[CONCAT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11404025/470530)` might be more portable?

Answer (score 4):

You can also use least() and greatest() together with `distinct`. That would preserve the individual values without the need to concatenate them.

```
select distinct least("from", "to"), greatest("from", "to")
from the_table;
```